# How to break into KD(Windbg) for Explorer crash

Tags: debugging, crash, kernel, windbg, usermode

I see a crash in Explorer.exe, due to our security s/w dll loaded in to the Explorer.exe.

The crash happens during the shutdown of the system. The VM is connected to the Kernel debugger. I don't see Kernel debugger breaks when exception happens. I tried all debug event filters. But I could not success.

**Can someone suggest me, why could not I see the break when there is an exception.**
I want to break into the debugger, exactly at the time of exception.
Can I use SXE ud "dllName" in kernelmode to notify my when a perticula dll gets unloaded?

the exception was
Explorer Crash, **"The instruction at 0x6ad88b5 refrernced memory at 0x0000000. The memory could not be read"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

1. Launch gflags.exe from WinDbg.
2. Go to "Image File" tab, type in "explorer.exe" and hit TAB key.
3. Check the first item "[Stop on Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558817%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)".

Now when explorer.exe crash and kernel debugger is connected, WinDbg should break.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the explorer crash happens when I issue shutdown, by this time all processes are terminated. This might be the reason, I could not catch the exception even with Gflags or "Windbg -I"

Answer (score 0):

First, loading or unloading of DLL will not cause break when debugging in Kernel mode, they work well when doing user mode debugging however.

i believe in kernel mode debugging you should be able to break, when kernel mode binaries like .SYS file are loaded or unloaded.

Now, to your question. One way could be,

1. set Windbg as the default postmortem debugger. *`windbg.exe -I`*.
   This will ensure that you break in the debugger when any exception occurs. But this would be user mode debugging.
2. Next, given that you have a KD setup, just executing *`.breakin`*, will take you form user mode to kernel mode debugging.

Italic are debugger commands.

Comment: Unfortunately, the exception never happen , when I set the postmortem debugger, "Windbg -I". It run with no problem. :(

Comment: Windbg -I, should not really change anything in the working of explorer.exe.
If the exception does not occur it indicates that you have timing issue. i would recommend to execute the repro scenario multiple times. That may help you get a crash.

Or as @Peter suggested run it under gflags, that will you catch memory related issues upfront.

If it still does not repro, looks like the bug is gone, be happy :)

Comment: It was Thanks a lot its timing issue. We are using PeekMessage(&Msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE); If I use PM_NOREMOVE, it works fine.